# What does it mean "Everything in the Linux is file"

Tags: linux, files

I just read the post [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_03_01.html). It just said.

> This statement is true because there are special files that are more
>   than just files (named pipes and sockets, for instance), but to keep
>   things simple, saying that everything is a file is an acceptable
>   generalization. A Linux system, just like UNIX, makes no difference
>   between a file and a directory, since a directory is just a file
>   containing names of other files. Programs, services, texts, images,
>   and so forth, are all files. Input and output devices, and generally
>   all devices, are considered to be files, according to the system.

I think I just didn't understand it enough and well. and I didn't know how to understant it. How all the things in Linux(like device, process,net connection, program etc) are treated as a file? Could anyone ptell me more about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In order to truly understand, I'd recommend some reading about I/O operations in the C programming language. I find it easiest to understand that from a programming perspective when you deal with devices, socket, pipes, etc just as you do with files just like the Linux/Unix OSs do.
Moreover you can read [this value in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, not all things are files. Process is not a file. But device is file. You can do read/write  operations with devices. Also sockets can be bound to filesystem.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file

Answer (score 0):

How I interpreted that (As I read a similar article) statement was that everything is controlled like a file. Meaning, unlike other Operating Systems, each file is shown and can be controlled. But I that's how I interpreted it.